# Neo4j 2.2 NullPointerException when using indexed property with null value

Tags: neo4j

We are running Neo4j on Windows Server 2008 R2 with JRE 1.7.0_79.

When executing certain queries which hit an index, we are getting a `NullPointerException`.

The query looks like the one below:

`MATCH (assignee)<-[:ASSIGNED_TO]-(task:Task)-[instanceOfRel:INSTANCE_OF]->(distribution:Distribution)
WITH assignee, task, distribution, instanceOfRel.CountryUid AS applicableCountryUid
OPTIONAL MATCH (country:Country)
WHERE country.Uid = applicableCountryUid
RETURN assignee, task, distribution, country`

And the query fails on the `WHERE` clause if `applicableCountryUid` is `null`.

If the index is removed from the schema, the query will work fine.

A partial extract of the full exception stack is:

```
"Received an unexpected HTTP status when executing the request.The response status was: 400 Bad RequestThe response from Neo4j (which might include useful detail!) was: {  
"exception" : "NullPointerException",  "fullname" : "java.lang.NullPointerException",  
"stackTrace" : [ "org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.index.LuceneDocumentStructure$ValueEncoding$2.canEncode(LuceneDocumentStructure.java:90)", 
"org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.index.LuceneDocumentStructure.newQuery(LuceneDocumentStructure.java:219)", 
"org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.index.LuceneIndexAccessorReader.lookup(LuceneIndexAccessorReader.java:96)", 
"org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.store.DiskLayer.nodesGetFromIndexLookup(DiskLayer.java:601)", 
"org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.store.CacheLayer.nodesGetFromIndexLookup(CacheLayer.java:349)", 
"org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.StateHandlingStatementOperations.nodesGetFromIndexLookup(StateHandlingStatementOperations.java:591)",
 "org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.ConstraintEnforcingEntityOperations.nodesGetFromIndexLookup(ConstraintEnforcingEntityOperations.java:210)",
```

This doesn't seem to affect the queries in earlier 2.1.x versions of Neo4j, but we are only seeing this issue with 2.2.0 and 2.2.2.

Is there a known issue or workarounds for working with the indices without rewriting queries?

Comment: Looks like a bug report to send, although "null values are bad" (tm).

Comment: I'm getting this one too. The query is as simple as that: MATCH (ret:`Transaction}`)  WHERE ret.hash = {hash}  RETURN ret. There is index on the hash. Query should not throw NPEs. Did you file bug report ? Happens with 2.2.2

Answer (score 0):

Are the results meaningful when `applicableCountryUid` is `null`? The `WHERE` clause doesn't make much sense then.

Maybe you can filter out the `null` cases:

```
MATCH (assignee)<-[:ASSIGNED_TO]-(task:Task)-[instanceOfRel:INSTANCE_OF]->(distribution:Distribution)
WHERE has(instanceOfRel.CountryUid)
WITH assignee, task, distribution, instanceOfRel.CountryUid AS applicableCountryUid
OPTIONAL MATCH (country:Country)
WHERE country.Uid = applicableCountryUid
RETURN assignee, task, distribution, country
```

Comment: Martin, we have explored that option using coalesce() and also using has(), but we are talking potentially dozens of queries that need to be updated and tested.  Approximately half of our 600+ unit tests fail with with 2.2.x with indices.  It's an option on the table, but I think it would be better if we could find a platform workaround.